# WriteProcessMemory/ReadProcessMemory fail

Tags: winapi

I tried using both ReadProcessMemory() and WriteProcessMemory() in my application,but in both cases I get one result - Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.

Has anyone met that error code before? I'm using Vista SP2,I tried to run as admistrator,but I till get that erorcode.

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using (the ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory calls)?

Comment: It's delpi,but I don't use VirtualProtectEx.I only want an example of VirtualProtectEx in C/Delphi.Anythng ill be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you call VirtualProtectEx to set the correct protection level on the memory you want to read/write.

After thinking about it, it's probably not the problem since most memory has read access enabled, but to set the protection level do something like this (in C++)

(no error checking and just using a random memory address, but you should get the idea)

```
char buffer[256];
DWORD oldProtect = 0;
DWORD numRead = 0;
VirtualProtectEx( hProc, (LPVOID)0x77810F34, 256, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect );
ReadProcessMemory( hProc, (LPVOID)0x77810F34, buffer, 256, &numRead );
VirtualProtectEx( hProc, (LPVOID)0x77810F34, 256, oldProtect, NULL ); //restore the original protection when you're done
```

Comment: Do I have to call it on all the addresses or can I call it for whole process memory? could you show an example,please!

Comment: It will most likely fail if you try to call it for the whole process memory, so you should call it for just the memory you want to access.

Comment: But it may be that you're not passing a valid argument in one of the slots, so it would be a good idea to post some of your code, even if it's in Delphi, if this isn't the problem.